# Update a field of an existing table with Auto Increment Logic

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a table with the following data,

```
          Product
-----------------------------
ID   Name ProductTypeID Order
1     A        1          0
2     B        1          0
3     D        2          0
4     C        2          0
-----------------------------------
-----------------------------------
-----------------------------------
```

I need to update the Order so that it value become,

```
          Product
-----------------------------
ID   Name ProductTypeID Order
1     A        1          1
2     B        1          2
3     D        2          1
4     C        2          2
-----------------------------------
-----------------------------------
-----------------------------------
```

See it is increasing the Order as AutoIncrement for each ProductTypeID.

Comment: @Freelancer, I have an existing table. I want to update the table's Order column by auto-incrementing this for each producttype, like 1,2,3......

Comment: instead of 1,2,1,2 u wanted order column  as 1,2,3,4 ????

Comment: @Freelancer, for each ProductTypeID. For ProductTypeID = 1, I need 1,2,3,4... and ProductTypeID = 2, I need 1,2,3,4.........

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you want to do is get the sort the records within partitions. The [query to do what you want is this](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ddc04/10):

```
WITH sorted AS (
    SELECT id, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ProductTypeId ORDER BY id ASC) as rownum
    FROM product
)
UPDATE product
SET [order] = s.rownum
FROM product p
   INNER JOIN sorted s on (p.id = s.id);
```

Answer (score 2):

tRY nOW

```
 Update product  Set  [order]= Case  when Not Exists (Select * from
 product a where  a.ProductTypeID =product.ProductTypeID  and a.id
 <product.ID )
     tHEN 1
     eLSE 
     ((Select Count([ORDER]) from product  b where 
     b.ProductTypeID =product.ProductTypeID  and b.ID <product.id)+1)
    eND
```

Comment: its problem in insert u are giving varchar to int