# Why am I geting null when i use max instead of count

Tags: sql, sql-server

I answered the following question [question link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16248517/update-a-field-of-an-existing-table-with-auto-increment-logic/). But i fount stringe Behaviour.
when i write this

```
Update product  Set  [order]= Case  when Not Exists (Select * from
 product a where  a.ProductTypeID =product.ProductTypeID  and a.id
 <product.ID )
     tHEN 1
     eLSE 
     ((Select cOUNT([ORDER])+1 from product  b where 
     b.ProductTypeID =product.ProductTypeID  and product.ID <product.id)+1)
    eND
```

It works well but when i write ...'

```
Update product  Set  [order]= Case  when Not Exists (Select * from
     product a where  a.ProductTypeID =product.ProductTypeID  and a.id
     <product.ID )
         tHEN 1
         eLSE 
         ((Select Max([ORDER])+1 from product  b where 
         b.ProductTypeID =product.ProductTypeID  and product.ID <product.id)+1)
        eND
```

It's gives null in else situation i dont understand why?Can Anyone Explain this when i missing why its getting null when i use Max.Here is sql fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1e15d/1 where i use count when i use Max it gives null why?

Comment: but it both reutrn int if i apply to int column see the question link.....when i use count it work but when i use Max it return null doesnt...

Comment: no it not....its when i use count int it works but when i use Max in place of count its gives null...why it is ...lyk that...]

Comment: i just wana know why it gives null when i use Max in above...sql statement

Comment: MAX will return NULL if you have NULL in your column. COUNT will just count the rows, it doesn't care what the values are.

Comment: If you select from `product`, do you see non-null `[ORDER]` values?

Comment: @sashkello idont have null in my table

Comment: take a look:  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/12880

Comment: yeah i understand what u say...it gives null when.it have null but my table didnt have null values @bummi

Comment: it also gives null values if condition is not fitting ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is that `count` returns zero for an empty result, but `max` returns null for an empty result.

You have `product.ID <product.id` in your condition in the subquery, which will always be false as you are comparing a field to itself. That will make the result from the subquery empty.

It should be `b.ID <product.id` to compare the value in the table in the subquery to a value in the table in the outer query.

So neither query works as intended, but when you use `count` you don't get a null value from the empty result.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this(for mysql):

```
select ifnull(max(column), 0)   when max() return null, it give you 0.
```

Comment: i dont have null in my table friend